# Web Audio API, get the output from the soundcard

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Can it be done?

If so, any information on the subject is greatly appreciated.
(If not with the Web Audio API, is there some other API that lets me achieve this?)

Comment: It is [possible with HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#widl-NavigatorUserMedia-getUserMedia-void-MediaStreamOptions-options-NavigatorUserMediaSuccessCallback-successCallback-NavigatorUserMediaErrorCallback-errorCallback), with your system's recording device set to "Stereo Mix". Here is one of those plugins with Flash as a fallback: https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/

Comment: Please specify more exactly what you need. A single half-sentence in the title is not clear enough to give you exact answers.

Comment: I have a project where I currently play an audio file and on animationframe get the **frequencyData** from it. I want to be able to do the exact same thing but with audio outputted directly from the soundcard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derek is correct. If You have a realtek card (I don't know about support from other manufacturers) You set it to stereo mix, and set the stereo mix to default microphone. You can then create a source node linked with your mic using `navigator.getUserMedia`.. Google and You Will find it.

I just made a fiddle for you: [Audio from soundcard](http://jsfiddle.net/MarijnS95/qHWM7/6/)

EDIT: the link now goes to the right version of the jsfiddle (the other one had the bars wrong).

Comment: That´s great! Any idea on how to achieve this on OSX?

Comment: @AlexLawrence honestly I have no idea... If there is a way to send your computer audio output to a virtual microphone, you can. Else you can connect your audio output to microphone input to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I've been digging for the last few days but can't seem to find the solution on how to connect audio output to microphone input. @MarijnS95 do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: @DanOchiana All I know about is the method mentioned with "stereo mix". I have no idea if newer solutions (some sort of generic loopback) exist, nor if modern sound cards/Windows versions still support this feature.

Comment: @AlexLawrence you can achieve this on OSX by using iShowU Audio Capture, just got it working

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to capture global audio output with `Web Audio API` for audio cards that support Stereo Mix feature, otherwise you could use Virtual Audio Cable.

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bomzj/beap6n2g/

Comment: Hi Maksim, the jsfiddle only seems to support capturing audio from recording devices like microphone, not output audio from speakers. Can you confirm that's what you intended?

Comment: @mlfan as far as I remember, I changed default device from Microphone Array to Stereo Mix in Control Panel -> Sound. After that I was able to choose that device and capture sound coming from audio output (speakers).