# Access/process system audio with Javascript/Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

Is it possible to access system audio using the Web Audio API, in order to visualize or apply an equalizer to it? It looks like it's possible to hook up system audio to an input device that Web Audio API can access (i.e. [Web Audio API, get the output from the soundcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015686/web-audio-api-get-the-output-from-the-soundcard)); however ideally I would like to be able to process all sound output without making any local configuration changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  The closest you could get is installing a loopback audio device on the user's systems, like Soundflower on OSX, and use that as the default audio output device.  It's not possible without local config changes.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I suppose this is how other equalizer apps like Boom 2 work. Do you know if a similar loopback mechanism is necessary to achieve the same thing on Android/iOS?

Comment: yes it is.  Not sure if they're available, actually.

Comment: What local config changes would those be?

Comment: installing a loopback driver.  I meant, it's not possible without the user doing something locally to their setup.

Comment: After installing loop-back adapter  how java script can access system audio ?