# Tokbox Share System sound during screen sharing

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I am trying to create a screen sharing app through Tokbox but I am not able to share the system audio. Instead, it is using the microphone to share the audio. Can you please suggest if it is possible to share system sound (like music etc.) rather than microphone?

Comment: There is an option **enableStereo:true** for initPublisher() method but it doesn't seems working.

Comment: enableStereo is not about sharing your audio through screensharing. It's about streaming a stereo audio stream instead of mono (which is default). It only makes sense if you have a stereo microphone or if you're streaming a stereo audio file eg. in this sample app https://opentok.github.io/opentok-web-samples/Stereo-Audio/

It should be possible though to stream the audio from your machine on Windows when screensharing, but not Mac or Linux. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=223639

Comment: @AdamUllman Thanks Adam. So what do you suggest, what should I do to share system's audio along with microphone and screensharing? Is it possible with tokbox? 
Basically, I want my video editing guys to share their screen with others so it is necessary to get system audio as well as mic input.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access the system audio from JavaScript on Linux and Mac. As Adam mentions in the comment, you can get the system audio along with the screen on Windows.

For non-Windows you would need to use a native application to pipe the system audio output back into a virtual microphone, then use TokBox to access the microphone as normal.

See [Access/process system audio with Javascript/Web Audio API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594405/access-process-system-audio-with-javascript-web-audio-api)

If you want to combine a screenshare with a microphone you will need to use the new custom audio source option (available from v2.13.0) combined with the screenshare video source:

```
Promise.all([
  OT.getUserMedia({ videoSource: null}),
  OT.getUserMedia({ videoSource: 'screen' }),
]).then(([audioStream, videoStream]) => {
  const audioSource = audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0];
  const videoSource = videoStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
  const publisher = OT.initPublisher({ audioSource, videoSource });
  session.publish(publisher);
});
```

If you want to stream 2 audio tracks then you will need to use multiple publishers. One publisher would have the screenshare video combined with the audio from the normal microphone. The other publisher would only have the virtual microphone (which has the system audio piped to it) and no video. You should use OT.getDevices() to determine which microphone should belong to each publisher.

You may be able to use the WebAudio API to combine the audio from both real and virtual microphones into a single track so you only need a single publisher, but that requires more effort.

Make sure enableStereo is turned on and audioBitrate is set to 64000 (or more) for the publisher that's streaming music.

If you need to support all operating systems then you could detect the OS based on the user agent and execute the appropriate strategy accordingly.