# Possible to process all sounds from webpage with javascript simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, audio

I've played around with the web audio api before, but it's a very specific and unambiguous that it wants to connect all the sources together to the destination for it to work. However it seems given how iframes and other ways sound can be introduced there'd need to be an extremely elaborate script to tie in new sources to an analyzer node headed to the output.

*Note* I'm not talking about routing a stream from a microphone like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015686/web-audio-api-get-the-output-from-the-soundcard), there shouldn't be any permission required. Also I'm not talking about audio sources already hooked into the web audio api, there are a ton of examples about processing audio from inside the web audio api. I'm curious if there's a generic way to process audio on a page before (or after) it hits the speakers.

Essentially I was curious if anyone has seen or built an application that's reactive to audio in html and or has thoughts on putting something like this together.

The solution I have in mind would be a script which triggers when media is played and attaches the media source to the web audio api > an analyzer node > destination. I haven't found any javascript event that appears to work in this way.

Comment: What's your question?  What do iframes have to do with it?  And, what makes you think this has to be complicated?  Why is there an analyser node?

Comment: My perception is that it's complicated because the api wants you to attach the audio sources to the routing graph (I'm looking to do fft transforms so that's why I mentioned the analyzer node). But in a generic sense you don't have control over whether an audio source was created in javascript, or maybe the source was created inside of an iframe (cors issue). You seem to think this would be easy, what would you do?

Comment: I don't know what I would do because I don't know what you are trying to do.  Otherwise, I would have answered your question.  What does CORS have to do with the Web Audio API?  Where do iframes come into play?

Comment: If you select a `<audio>` or `<video>` element in the iframe, I think you should be able to create a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` using [`createMediaElementSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource), but it would likely be subject to CORS restrictions.

Comment: I think I can clear up my question here: there are multiple ways of getting audio to play. I was wondering if in fact there was a generic way of processing audio using javascript on a webpage. In other words, ignoring where the audio is coming from would it be possible to have it processed by javascript?

I think Useless Code you're on track with where I've run into the problem. I'm not guaranteed an <audio> or <video> element is the source and if it's not, what would you do to redirect the source to the web audio api. I brought up iframes to address embedded sources (eg youtube) cors issue