# How to capture the speaker's output using the Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

On a web page, I would like to capture the current speaker's output (the global audio output of the computer).

I saw that the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) is capable to do a great number of things, but it is capable to do such thing?

If yes, how? If no, are there any - simple, if possible - alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with the Web Audio API, unless the user's sound card driver provides a *Wave Out* or similar loopback device, in which case you could record from that as if it was any other input device. These are few and far between though, and the naming tends to vary per device so you would either need to let the user choose or make a guess.

I'm not sure if there any true alternatives --- at least ones that will work on every platform and browser. Windows provides a [loopback recording API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd316551(v=vs.85).aspx) which you could maybe access with a Java applet as a suggestion, but I don't think it'll work out how you want it to.

Comment: You are right. My question is duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015686/web-audio-api-get-the-output-from-the-soundcard