# How can I make an audio visualizer that will respond to the sound generate by the page

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm currently working on a drum machine project and I generate the sound by using setTimeOut to different individual clips. I want to add an audio visualizer to my project function like this one https://drumbit.app/. However, visualizers generated by Web Audio API need a specific source file that I don't have. So, I want to know if there's a way to make the sound generate by the page(my app) as a source of Web Audio API.

Comment: You can create tones and perhaps more complex sounds from the audio API but it would be easier to have source files to play. Lots of info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Advanced_techniques).

Comment: You could semi-feasibly use the stereo mix (soundcard) as an input device, as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015686/web-audio-api-get-the-output-from-the-soundcard) alludes to - however it is not available everywhere and would require most users who have it to specifically enable it. Even then, you still have to create an audioContext and attach an analyser to it to create the visualiser - it makes much more sense to buffer your clips and play them directly through the audioContext instead.

Comment: What are these clips and where do they come from?